# A cleaner Settings (or other properties) proxy class

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, proxy, reflection.emit

Is there a common implementation practice for reducing code (especially the duplicate strings) here?

```
public class Settings {
    private static settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    public string MRUList {
        get {
            return settings["MRUList"];
        }
        set {
            settings["MRUList"] = value;
        }
    }

    public string AnotherSetting {
        get {
            return settings["AnotherSetting"];
        }
        set {
            settings["AnotherSetting"] = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I don't know, maybe an existing NuGet package that Emits an injectable settings class based on an interface? (REMEMBER: This is an *example of an approach* to this problem. If you think my idea is foolish, suggest another please. There's always gotta be a hater...)

```
public interface Settings {

    public string MRUList { get; set; }

    public string AnotherSetting { get; set; }

}

MappedSettings Settings = CrazyMapper.Generate<Settings>(Properties.Settings.Default);
```

AutoMapper could technically do this, I suppose, except it would either:

1. Copy all the settings each time I access settings
2. Not contain up-to-date setting information

Comment: Why would you make a simple and safe story complicated and error-prone? Also, this would produce a performance disaster...

Comment: 1. Why do you say reducing duplication of magic strings in code increases the likelyhood of defects? 2. Since the dynamic code is only generated once at startup, and used for a large number of relatively infrequently accessed settings, why do you say it would be a performance disaster? 3. You are overlooking a key reason AutoMapper and other similar tools exist... for convenience and to reduce drudgery. 4. When code is easier to read, it's easier to maintain. 5. Remember, please focus on the question asked.

Comment: Why worry about the duplicated strings? The compiler interns them, so the string is only stored once. From a coding standpoint, you might consider creating a const: `const string MruListProperty = "MRUList";`

Comment: Totally agree, Jim, however, if there is another generally accepted way to do this, I would use it. That's why I'm asking. I'm here to learn from the community rather than assume I've seen everything.

Comment: @shannon 1. Because there would be a massive amount of really horrible complicated code running under the hood - if you're really worried about the magic strings here: well, that's as easy as using constants ;-) 2. I of course didn't make tests, but I guess this alone would be 10 - 15 times slower than accessing the settings in the normal way.

Comment: @Thomas: 1. Complex code written once is VERY often more reliable than simple code written dozens (or even hundreds) of times. See my reply to/agreement with Jim regarding constants above. 2. I would happily accept 10-15 times slower for the usage of settings I have in mind. Let's move on please :)

Comment: @Thomas: p.s. if you do write and run tests to prove it's a bad idea, please send me the code so that I can use it in my app ;). And hey, note that I called my hypothetical generator "CrazyMapper"... should have been your first clue that I was just thinking out loud.

Comment: @shannon No need to tell me this. I CAN read. But you thought out loud a bad idea anyway... ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: A bad idea in your head, so you've mentioned. You should subscribe to the "Reflection" channel here, it would apparently provide you endless amusement. At any rate, the "bad idea" wasn't the question here. As I mentioned, it was demonstrative of the problem I was solving, not the solution I expected.

Comment: Why don't you access your setting like this Properties.Settings.Default.MRUList as intend?

Comment: This looks like something that could be autogenerated with T4.

Comment: Simon: nice to see an actual suggestion ;) T4 could actually generate code even from an OEM settings file, I suppose, although that's probably a non-programming team maintaining that file on most projects.